# .msg preview in 64Bit application not working

Tags: outlook, 64-bit, preview, msg

We are having problems with our 64Bit Application (Addin for Outlook). There is a feature that should display a preview of *.msg files in our application. It works fine with windows explorer and in Outlook 32Bit. When I try to open the file with our 64Bit application an error occurs:

**"Either there is no default mail client or the current mail client cannot fulfill the messaging request. Please run Microsoft Outlook and set it as the default mail client."**

I tried everything the internet suggests...
- Repair Outlook
- Outlook as default mail client
- New Outlook profile
- ...

It is NO option to install a 32Bit version of our software or to just "disable" this feature...

Does anyone have a solution that fixes this error?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected - a 64 bit app cannot load 32 bit dlls (that is what the MAPI system is).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the future has the same problem:

We fixed this issue. Therefore we use this bits of code:

```
[..]
// read this documentation for explanation...
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtypesbase/ne-wtypesbase-clsctx 
const uint CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER = 4;
uint hResult = CoCreateInstance(ref guid, null,
                CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, ref IID_IUnknown, out instance);

mCurrentPreviewHandler = instance;
[..]

[DllImport("ole32.Dll")]
static public extern uint CoCreateInstance(ref Guid guid,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object inner,
    uint context,
    ref Guid uuid,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object rReturnedComObject);
[..]
```